# Javascript look for the same value in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function success() {
    var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Title').GetValue(); 
    for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
        var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
        console.log(item.get_item('Title'));
    }

}
```

And I want to know if any item has the same value of currentTitle. Any kind of help will be kindly appreciated

Comment: what's the point of the two `var item =` lines? The second one will overwrite/destroy the value you got on the previous one...

Comment: `if (curretTitle === item.get_item('Title')) {...}` ??

Comment: Im really sorry i already edited the post and deleted the second var=item it was my bad

Comment: To "look for the same value", use the equality operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) in conjunction with an `if` statement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
function success() {
  var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Title').GetValue(); 
  for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
      var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
      if(currentTitle == item.get_item('Title')){
           return true; // or item
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

// Old Answer: If you were working with an Array....

If you want to know if any items match then try Array.prototype.some

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

(Depending on what browser you want to support)

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element > 10;  
}
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);  // false
[12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10); // true
```

So for your case something like:

```
allItems.some(function(item){
   return item.get_item('Title') == curretTitle;
});
```

Usually people want to find the exact match, is that what you want?

Comment: @stujo Thank you very much for the help so the one I need to use is the third choice? and as epascarello said im not working with an array

Comment: and yes i want to find the exact match

Comment: The first one (the implementation of success) is the one you should try

Comment: If you want the found item change the return from `true` to `item`